# Why is $GF(p^n)$ unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I'm having trouble understanding why exactly $GF(p^n)$ is unique up to isomorphism.

I know that the proof begins by claiming that $GF(p^n)$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $x^{p^n}-x\in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.

I don't understand why the splitting field of a polynomial is unique though.

Could someone help explain this to me?

Comment: The uniqueness of splitting fields is a theorem proved in all texts on Galois theory. See "splitting fields and tensor products" at https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ for a slick proof.

Comment: A slightly different take (but not really) would be to observe that all the elements of all the fields of cardinality $p^n$ are zeros of $x^{p^n}-x$. So if $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$, then, as $f(x)$ has a zero in $K=\Bbb{Z}_p[x]/(f(x))$, $f(x)$ must be a factor of $x^{p^n}-x$. Meaning that $f(x)$ has a zero $\alpha$ also in any other field $K'$ of size $p^n$. The evaluation homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ to $K'$, $g(x)\mapsto g(\alpha)$, then yields an isomorphism $K\simeq K'$.